# How to change the style of the mat-pseudo-checkbox of only a specific component?

Tags: css, angular, checkbox, angular-material

I want only the `mat-pseudo-checkbox` of a specific component will be affected.
I don't want all of the `mat-pseudo-checkbox` of the whole project will be changed.

When I'm using `::ng-deep` to change the style of the `mat-pseudo-checkbox`, all the `mat-pseudo-checkbox` of the whole project are affected, and not only the `mat-pseudo-checkbox` inside a specific component as I expected.

My code, placed in the style of the specific component:

```
::ng-deep .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
   display: none !important;
}
```

The element I want to be affected:
`<mat-option></mat-option>`

Comment: you can apply pesudo on specific element using id or specific class so it don't effect other

Answer (score 0):

you can add a special class to the needed mat-pseudo-checkbox, for example

```
<mat-pseudo-checkbox class="needed-element">
```

and add the class to CSS selector

```
::ng-deep .needed-element .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `multiple` directive from `<mat-select></mat-select>` the checkboxes should not be displayed.

If you want to do it using CSS then you need to add a panel class, this will allow you to specify the options that you want to modify.

```html
<mat-select multiple panelClass="test-class">
...
</mat-select>
```

```css
::ng-deep .test-class .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
  display: none !important;
}
```

to avoid using ::ng-deep you can place the CSS rules in the styles.css file at the root

Answer (score 0):

In your top-level `styles.scss/styles.css`, add the styles scoped to your component's selector:

SCSS:

```
my-component {
  .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
    // custom styles here
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
my-component .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
  // custom styles here
}
```